# How can I hard reset my Windows 8 phone (which keys do I press?)

Tags: 8.0

Is it possible to hard reset a Windows 8 phone?

I've carried out a factory reset which has seemingly got stuck and I want to try and abort this.

I can't seem to find out whether there is a key combination which will either reset the phone or access a "system menu" or similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To ["soft reset"](http://allaboutwindowsphone.com/flow/item/16201_The_Windows_Phone_8_soft_reset.php) a Windows Phone you press volume down + power key for 10 seconds. This is the equivalent of pulling out a battery on a phone with a removable battery.

Answer (score 12):

I think you caschw is describing a soft-reset.

Windows Phone 8 hard-reset goes like this:

- Turn off your phone.
- Hold volume-down.
- Keep holding volume-down and press power button for about 3 seconds.
- Let go of the power button, but keep holding the volume down until image/icon on the screen appears.

Almost done - now proceed with the following sequence:

- Let go of holding the volume-down and press:
- volume-up
- volume-down
- power
- volume-down

That kicks the phone into a hard-reset sequence, which should take about 40-60 seconds.

If you did all of that correctly, the phone will take you to the "Welcome to your Windows Phone, let's get started screen."

Resources: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bUeaGG2D52E