# Unable to turn on/off wifi

Tags: lumia, wifi

I am having Lumia 620,i am unable to turn on/off my wifi.In the settings menu it is showing as turned on for Wifi but when i click on the wifi option it shows as off.I am unable to turn it on and it not connecting it to any wifi available nearby and not searching any as well.

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to turn Wi-Fi on? Do you happen to have internet sharing enabled (Settings -> Internet sharing)? Have you tried restarting your phone?

Comment: The turn on/off button remains disabled .My internet sharing is disabled,and i have tried by restarting my phone as well

Comment: Did you install the Windows Phone 8.1 update preview for Developers ? If not, which version of the OS are you running ?

Comment: Doesn't airplane mode shut it off too?

Answer (score 1):

1. Restart your phone.
2. Check that Internet Sharing is off.
3. Soft reset (Power key + Volume Down key for 15 seconds).
4. Hard reset ([Power Key + Volume Down Key + Camera Key](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/3212/8768)) if necessary. A hard reset returns your phone "to the same state it was in the first time you turned it on". If you had backup enabled, you could restore some data after the reset, but [you'll still lose other data](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/6211/what-am-i-going-to-lose-if-i-hard-reset-my-phone).

Comment: since you've put IF NECESSARY in capitals, how about explaining what will happen on a hard reset, why someone might not want to do it, and how they will know it is necessary or worth doing?